# For an article in the paper, one new or one news?

Tags: grammatical-number

I was wondering if when talking about an article in the newspaper or a blog, if there was an s for on new or news ?

Comment: One knew this would cause difficulties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, your wording is unclear here - 'if there was an s for on new or news' is not intelligible english.

*News* is not a plural.  'New' is a different word, and even though 'news' is based on 'new' etymologically, they are not otherwise related.  You also never pluralize 'new'.

You usually don't refer to a single article or news story as 'news', although you might in the sense of '*it was on the news*'.  All the articles, TV stories and so forth are collectively the 'news'.  So generally you're referring to all the news-based media published when you say the word, or define it such as '*today's news*' to refer to a specific time period.

So, while an article in the paper might be *in* the news, it is not the news, or a new.

Answer (score 1):

A particular article in the paper is just that:

> an [news] *article*  or sometimes a *piece*
>
> [article](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/article) :  a written composition in prose, usually nonfiction, on a specific topic, forming an independent part of a book or other publication, as a newspaper or magazine.
> [piece](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/piece) 5 : a literary, journalistic, artistic, dramatic, or musical composition

if it's in space allocated to a particular writer it might be called

> a column or an editorial.

Answer (score 0):

*News* is an uncountable noun.  You can talk about one *piece* of news, or two *pieces* of news.

Often, it's just *the news*.  For example, *Have you heard the good news about the kidnapped baby? The police found him alive.*